# $\pi_i(E,F)\to \pi_{i-1}(F)$ injective if $F\hookrightarrow E$ is nullhomotpic

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fiber-bundles, fibration

This question pertains to Grumpy Parsnip's answer here: [Fiber bundle with null-homotopic fiber inclusion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1362820/fiber-bundle-with-null-homotopic-fiber-inclusion)

The claim is:
If $F\to E\to B$ is a fiber bundle with $F\to E$ nullhomotopic, then the LES of homotopy groups breaks into **split** SES's:

$$0\to \pi_i(E)\to \pi_i(B)\to \pi_{i-1}(F)\to 0$$

In the answer linked above, it is claimed that a splitting is given as follows:

$$\begin{align}
& \pi_{i-1}(F)\to \pi_i(E,F)\stackrel{\cong}{\to}\pi_i(B) \\
&[f]\mapsto[(\widetilde{f},f)]
\end{align}$$

where $\widetilde f:D^i\to E$ is an extension of the composite $S^{i-1}\stackrel{f}{\to} F\to E$ which is nullhomotopic.

What's not clear to me is why this is well-defined. **That is, why is the boundary map $\pi_i(E,F)\to \pi_{i-1}(F)$ injective?** Is this true for arbitrary pairs of spaces $(E,F)$ with $F\hookrightarrow E$ nullhomotpic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the LES of the pair $(F,E)$ shows you that the boundary map you talk about is surjective, so it's rarely injective.

For the splitting, don't pick arbitrary extensions. Choose the ones coming from a fixed nullhomotopy $H\colon[0,1]\times F\rightarrow E$. In other words, if $[f]\in\pi_{i-1}(F)$ then compose $\operatorname{id}_{[0,1]}\times f$ with your fixed homotopy. This descends to an extension $\tilde{f}$ which will give you the splitting.

Comment: Right makes sense, thanks!