# Lifting fibre's $\pi_n$ to base's $\pi_{n+1}$ is a homomorphism

Tags: algebraic-topology, fiber-bundles

I am following up to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1362820/fiber-bundle-with-null-homotopic-fiber-inclusion). The setup is a fibre bundle $F \hookrightarrow E \to B$ such that $F \hookrightarrow E$ is nullhomotopic.

One starts with a map $g:S^{n-1} \to F$. This lifts to a map $\tilde{g}:D^n \to E$. (One can construct this explicitly; I did, but don't think it's necessary.) This $\tilde{g}$ represents a homotopy class in $\pi_n(E,F) \cong \pi_n(B)$.

I want to show that $[g] \mapsto [\tilde{g}]$ is well-defined, in fact a homomorphism. Right now I am still stuck on well-definedness.

**Well-definedness**

Let $g,h$ be homotopic maps $S^{n-1} \to F$. Then $\tilde{g},\tilde{h}$ are maps $(D^n,S^{n-1}) \to (E,F)$. Denote by $G:S^{n-1} \times I \to F$ the homotopy between $g,h$. We want a homotopy $\tilde{G}:D^n \times I \to E$ between $\tilde{g},\tilde{h}$. I thought to use the HLP; but for this, we need a homotopy $D^n \times I \to B$, whose construction is not obvious to me. How is this homotopy obtained? (Is the HLP even the right tool for this?)

Update: I think I was correct in that the HLP is too much for this problem. Let $H:F \times I \to E$ be the nullhomotopy from $F$ to $*$. Then define a homotopy $D^n \times I \to E$ by $(x,t) \mapsto H(G(x/|x|,t),|x|)$ and $(0,t) \mapsto *$. This is a perfectly good homotopy between lifts of $g,h$ to maps $(D^n,S^{n-1}) \to (E,F)$. This suffices.

**Homomorphism**

I am not sure how to begin this part, and am working on it now. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just a suggestion: Elements of $\pi_n(X,*)$ can also be represented as maps $(I^n,\partial I^n) \to (X,*)$. With respect to this representation, the formulas representing addition become a bit easier to bookkeep.